# Call constructor to initialize variables

Tags: c++, class

I have the following class definition in C++ :

```
class foo {
private:
   int      a,b,c;

   foo();     // constructor
   void     setup(int x, int y);
   void     some_function_that_changes_a_b_c();
}


foo::foo() {
   a = b = c = 0;
}

void foo::setup(int x, int y) {
    foo();    // <-- I use this to make sure a,b,c are initialized
    a = x;
    b = y;    // <-- c is left unchanged!
}

void foo::some_function_that_changes_a_b_c() {
    // here's some code that changes variables a,b,c
}
```

And then I have a code that uses this class:

```
foo  *a = new foo;
a->setup(1,2);
a->some_function_that_changes_a_b_c();
a->setup(5,7);   // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

The problem is that on the second call to setup(), it doesnt run the foo() constructor to reset my values or a,b,c , so the c variable stays with the old value it was on the call to some_function_that_changes_a_b_c(), I tested this with the debugger and it seems like on the second call, foo() is addressing a different memory space for the variables.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: **Books:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: you should use a function to initialize the properties instead of directly doing it in the constructor

Comment: This has already been addressed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402097/calling-class-constructor-in-member-function-c-solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, constructor is only called once when the object is constructed, and not anymore in your class method. In your code

```
void foo::setup(int x, int y) {
    foo();  // ==> this line
}
```

A temporary foo object will be created, which is independent of the current `this` object, and therefore the `a`, `b` and `c` fields of `this` object will be unchanged.

In order to do what you have in mind, create a *class method*, say `foo::reset()`, and call it from inside `foo::setup()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call your constructor after the object has been created. Put the functionality into a protected `reset()` function that is called from both your constructor and the `setup` function.

**Background:** Your call to `foo()` in `setup` does not reinitialize the object, but create a second local object that is never used. In general, you should refrain from explicitly calling constructors unless you absolutely know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo();    // <-- I use this to make sure a,b,c are initialized
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't do that. It creates and destroys a temporary object. You can't call a constructor directly; they are only used to initialise objects at the start of their lifetime.

You could reassign your object with a freshly initialised one:

```
*this = foo();
```

or you could move the body of the constructor into a `reset` function, and call that whenever you want to restore the initial state.

My preferred option would be use separate objects rather than trying to reuse a modified one, and to perform all the "setup" when initialising each object:

```
foo a(1,2);
a.some_function_that_changes_a_b_c();
foo b(5,7);  // known to be in a freshly initialised state
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is two-stage initialization.  This is unnecessary and clumsy in C++.  You need to realize two things

1. The constructor is called at the point of object creation
2. If you have an object to say `f.setup(1, 2, 3);` on, that means the constructor must have run already.

now:

```
foo f; // calls foo() with f
f.setup(1, 2, 3); // foo() has arleady been called
```

as Ying Xiong has pointed out, the `foo()` line creates a temporary object unrelated to the `this` you are working with.

Rather than two stage initialization (constructor, then initializer) you can have your constructor take variables and do the initialization

```
class foo {
  private:
   int      a,b,c;
  public:
   foo(int x, int y, int z);     // constructor
};

foo::foo(int x, int y, int z)
   : a(x),
   b(y),
   c(z)
{ }
```

and then instead construct with the values you want

```
foo f(1, 2, 3);
```

if you need to "reset" the values each time `setup` is called, then you're best to use a `reset` function, or similar.  Trying to call a constructor on yourself is possible but not very healthy.

```
void foo::reset() {
    a = b = c = 0;
}
```